# why we need to override terminate()?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, memory-leaks

My C++ program has an error:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

 char* foo()
 {
    char * mystr = new char[6];
    mystr = "Hello";
    return mystr ;
 }
 int main()
 {

 char* myString =foo();
 printf("%s \n", myString);

 delete [] myString ;

 } 


  ==27472== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
  ==27472==    at 0x4A07A12: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:409)
  ==27472==    by 0x4007EB: main (printHello.cpp:16)
  ==27472==  Address 0x4008f8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

If I remove `delete [] myString ;` it works well.

I should free the memory allocated on heap, right ?

But, why I got error, if I delete it.

Thanks

Comment: In C/C++ you cannot assign values to char arrays by using the '=' operator, you have to use strcpy (or better strncpy). C++ also introduces the std::string class, which does the job well.

Answer (score 8):

Because you are deleting memory you didn't allocate.  You allocate 6 bytes via "new", but then you reassign the var "mystr" to a completely different pointer (static string "Hello") that wasn't allocated by "new".  So you attempt to "delete" the static string "Hello" that wasn't allocated by you in the first place.  Here's the fix:

Change these lines:

```
 char * mystr = new char[6]; 
 mystr = "Hello";
```

To this:

```
char * mystr = new char[6]; 
strcpy(mystr, "Hello");
```

Alternatively, you could have "foo" just "**return "hello";**" and not delete the string in main.

Comment: if static string "Hello" is also allocated on heap, why we cannot delete it ?

Comment: @user: "Hello" was not allocated on the heap.

Comment: what is difference between static string and string ?

Comment: A 'string' is a null terminated sequence of characters in memory.  A 'static string' is a string in static memory (neither on the heap or the stack).

Answer (score 3):

`myString` wasn't allocated on the heap -- `foo` allocates a char array on the heap, but then you throw away the pointer to it and return a pointer to a static string (which is not on the heap).